# Find in referenced/linked MongoDB document, using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have 3 linked documents like:

```
{'_id':1, 'name':'abc', 'label':'actionA', 'prev':null}
{'_id':2, 'name':'pqr', 'label':'actionB', 'prev':ObjectId('1')}
{'_id':3, 'name':'xyz', 'label':'actionC', 'prev':ObjectId('2')}
```

Now I want to query a document whose 'name' is 'pqr' and also its previous/linked document should contains 'label' as 'actionA'.
All I want is it should find 'name' and check whether previous liked doc is available, if so then check its previous doc should have 'label' which I want.
It will be preferable if using some 1 line command something like:

```
db.collection.find({'$and'[{'name':'pqr'},{'prev': <gotoprev>({'label':'actionA'})}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using aggregation

### MongoDB 3.4 Solution

take advantage of the **`$graphLookup`** operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
   {  
      $match:{  
         "name":"pqr"
      }
   },
   {  
      $graphLookup:{  
         from:"collection",
         startWith:"$prev",
         connectFromField:"prev",
         connectToField:"_id",
         as:"parent",
         maxDepth:1,
         restrictSearchWithMatch:{  
            label:"actionA"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

---

### Mongodb 3.2

1. filter out document where `name != 'pqr'` in a **`$match`** stage
2. link parent an child with **`$lookup`**
3. unwind the resulting array with **`$unwind`**
4. finally filter out document where `parent.label != 'actionA'`

here is the query:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([  
       {  
          $match:{  
             "name":"pqr"
          }
       },
       {  
          $lookup:{  
             from:"collection",
             localField:"prev",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"prev"
          }
       },
       {  
          $unwind:"$prev"
       },
       {  
          $match:{  
             "prev.label":"actionA"
          }
       }
    ])
```

Comment: Can we have similarly for version 2.4 @felix ?

Comment: @JigyasuTailor, no idea for 2.4, but this version is deprecated since at least 2015, you shoudl really consider upgrading to 3.2 at least

Answer (score 0):

You can denormalise and store prev_label also in the referenced document (NoSQL way).

```
{'_id':1, 'name':'abc', 'label':'actionA', 'prev':null}
{'_id':2, 'name':'pqr', 'label':'actionB', 'prev':ObjectId('1'),'prev_label': 'actionA'}
{'_id':3, 'name':'xyz', 'label':'actionC', 'prev':ObjectId('2'),'prev_label': 'actionB'}
```

Then you can use find query for the result

```
db.collection.find({'$and'[{'name':'pqr'},{'prev_label': 'actionA'}]})
```

If label in original document is changed you can keep them updated in referenced documents with an update query

```
db.collection.update({'prev': updatedDocumentId},{'$set': {'prev_label': newLabel}}, multi=True)
```